# Maximal inequalities for square of partial sums

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, markov-chains

Let $S_n = \sum_{i \leq n} X_i$ be the partial sums of a nice sequence of random variables $X_i$. In my application, $X_i$ is a functional of a finite-state, irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain, so the $X_i$ are as bounded and mixing as you like. (I'd prefer not to assume stationarity for the $X_i$; and of course $S_n$ aren't stationary anyway.)

There are lots of inequalities for $S^*_N := \sup_{n \leq N} S_n - \mathbb{E} S_n$, since this is the sum of a nice mean-zero sequence. In my setting, these results give $S^*_N \leq C\sqrt{N}$. Unfortunately, in the application I need to work with $S_n^2$.

Question: are there any non-asymptotic inequalities on $\mathbb{E}\sup_{n \leq N}\left|S_n^2 - \mathbb{E} S_n^2\right|$? I would like the answer to be $\leq C\sqrt{N}$ (for some constant $C$, which presumably depends on the moments of the $X_i$), for the following reasons:

1. If the $X_i$ are iid, then $S_n^2 - \mathbb{E} S_n^2$ is a martingale, and Doob's maximal inequality gives $\leq C\sqrt{N}$.
2. Functional central limit theorem, as well as various stronger invariance principles, holds in this setting. All of these suggest that the largest deviation of $S_n^2$ from its expectation for $n \leq N$ should be $O(\sqrt{N})$.

(Edited to clarify the bound I actually want.)

Comment: Do you want inequalities on the _moments_ of $\sup_{n\leqslant N}S_N^2-\mathbb E[S_n^2]$ or a bound of this random variable. In the first case, this recent paper by Florence Merlevède and Magda Peligrad http://arxiv.org/pdf/1103.3242.pdf can help.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, but as far as I can tell, Florence Merlevède and Magda Peligrad consider the moments of the maximum of partial sums of a stationary sequence. How does that apply to the moments of $\max(S_n^2 - \mathbb{E} S_n^2)$? I can, of course, write $S_n^2$ as a partial sum, but it will then contain the large, strongly correlated variables $X_n S_{n-1}$ as summands. Am I missing something about that paper?

Comment: I see. In the paper there are inequalities on $\lVert \mathbb E_0(S_n^2)-\mathbb E(S_n^2)\rVert_{p/2}$ but it is not what you want.

Comment: It turns out that the question as I asked it is silly: the correct order of magnitude for the bounds is $N$, not $\sqrt{N}$, and then one might as well drop the centering. For my reference, though, a way of converting inequalities on finite-state Markov chains into iid random variables is to think of the (iid) excursions between successive visits to one of the states. This method is used e.g. in Chapter 17 of Meyn and Tweedie.